# Drupal 8 Views UI Block Frontpage Only

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-8

I created a block in /admin/structure/views to display the latest node of a custom content-type named News in the frontpage.
In /admin/structure/block, I placed my block in the right region and configured it so that it only shows in .

Then, if I go to a page I created in /admin/structure/views to display all the News, the block will take over each News's node.

Frontpage: http://i.imgur.com/2yFGnlo.png?2

News page: http://i.imgur.com/r2Jo9uv.png?2

How can I display the latest News in the frontpage without affecting the view page listing all the News

Thank you,
Keldus

Comment: Based on screenshots you've provided - it works just as it supposed to. On the front page there is a block with a latest news item ("Donec..."). On the all news Views page (with a sort criteria "by date", I guess) the latest item is the same item ("Donec..."), not a block. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Technically it is the same item, but I want to restrict the block only to the front page, so that the all news page show the suggestions `code * node--view--nouvelles--page-1.html.twig   * node--view--nouvelles.html.twig`  and not `code * node--view--infolettre--block-1.html.twig   * node--view--infolettre.html.twig`? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that this item is a block and not comes from a page view? In the latter case you can just set "Offset = 1" in a "Pager" section of your Views' settings page to skip the first item.

Comment: This is my block's settings: http://i.imgur.com/GN3LrsV.png
This is my page's settings: http://i.imgur.com/M38Y9fP.png
But I wish not to skip the first item. Is it possible?

Comment: Please, click on "Mini pager, 10 items" link (page's settings) and set "Offset" to 1. Maybe it would help. (I still believe that this item you want to get rid of is a part of a page, not a block.)

Comment: It is part of the page that's why I do not understand why it shows it as a block

Comment: The offset just removes completly the item. I guess In my previous comment I wrongly expressed my self, what I want is for my first item to be a news from the news page and not a news from the infolettre, but I don't know why a view block is applyed everywhere and not just where I asked it to be

Comment: This is my structure:http://i.imgur.com/CpRuwfj.png and this is my config for it http://i.imgur.com/oYsPbxY.png I guess Drupal just sucks on that point

Comment: Strange. In the first screenshot it should be "infolettre (Views)" in the CATEGORY column, not just "ifolettre". If you click on "Place" link, could you spot any other familiar block but with "(Views)" in the category?

Comment: That's because I was playing with the categories to see if it would change something, it didn't. I tried block, List (views), custom block, nothing worked.

Comment: *ah, I was wrong, on the second screenshot machine-readable-name contains "views_block_" so this block is the right one.

Comment: It might also be a problem with the cache, because when I clear it, then go to the frontpage, the node is set to be an "Infolettre", but when I clear it  and then go to the news page, the node is set to be a news page. I do not compute this in my head.

Comment: So, am I right that the problem is that this block displays on 1) front page 2) view's page, and should be only on front one? If so, please, try to move it another region and/or add to this region ("infolettre") some other block, maybe it's a problem with some custom code and this particular region.

Comment: In fact, the block is not displayed in the view's page, but is applayed to every content of type news that correspond to the criteria wich is not what I want and do not understand

Comment: The problem remains if you move this block to another region?

Comment: Yeah, I did'nt want to customize the fields, but what i'll do is change the format from content to field and load all the fields and work with it. It's been more than a week that I tried to fix this. Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome! Have no additional ideas so far(